# Can we install an app and register a user using deferred deep linking

Tags: branch.io

I'm considering using branch.io for my project.
Before I get too deep into it I'd like to sanity check a use case.

1)A user has already been created by an admin in our database.

2)We send the user a customised  link to install the app. The link contains a **uniqueID**

3)User clicks on link and installs the app.

4)When the app is installed we take the **uniqueID** from the link, use it to look the user up in our database and show their "admin created" data.

So to summarise all of that:

Is it possible install an app from a customised link and access data from the link after install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible with Branch! You can put as many key-value pairs as you like in a Branch link and during the initialization process, you can retrieve these key-value pairs in a JSON format, even after the install process. Then, you would perform some backend and routing logic with the value of the uniqueID.

To learn more and get started, please visit the docs here:

- [iOS](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/)
- [Android](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/)